# How to get value using getelementbyId for id as array

Tags: javascript, php

```
<input type="checkbox" id="time<?php echo $n . "[]"; ?>" name="time<?php echo $n . "[]"; ?>" value="<?php echo $row1['timeid']; ?>" onchange="chckrule(<?php echo $n  . $k; ?>)" />
```

This is my input checkbox having id and name and value as array. How to fetch the value using `getElementById`.
I used

```
for(var k=1;k<=2;k++)
{
  var x=document.getElementById('time'+k+).value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an array until PHP processes it. In HTML it is just an id ending with the characters `[]`.

```
document.getElementById('time' + k + '[]').value
```

Comment: You use the id of the second checkbox. An ID must be *unique* in a document.

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript or jquery

```
for(var k=1;k<=2;k++)
{
    var x=document.getElementById('time'+k+ '[]').value;
   alert(x)
  }
```

Comment: alright....but am not getting the value for k=2 and k=3 if the limit is set as 3.